# Delimit the area in that parameter space that contains 95.4% confidence

Tags: r, self-study, optimization, likelihood, parameterization

Given the equation
$y = fc + fe\times \sin(2\pi(x-t_0)/12)$

Considering the two parameters of amplitude fc and fe simultaneously, delimit (using the χ2 variation method) the area in that parameter space that contains 95.4% confidence.

```
months=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
frac=c(0.3690323, 0.3230706, 0.3095238, 0.2549206, 0.1850998, 0.05614035, 0.04584041, 0.06513057, 0.208254, 
       0.3004608, 0.344127, 0.3136713)
error= c(0.04628507 ,0.05000108, 0.02780694, 0.03403128, 0.0253194, 0.008280586, 0.01247297, 0.009350916, 0.02627754, 
         0.03296408,0.03841221, 0.03688875)


fc <- fe <- seq(0.0025, 1, 0.005)
chisq.table <- matrix(NA, 200, 200)


fun.to.minimize <- function(params,x,y,var) {
    fc <- params[1]
    fe <- params[2]
    t0 <- params[3]
    output <- sum(((y-fc-fe * sin(2* pi *(x- t0)/12))/var)^2)
    return(output)
}


fun.to.minimize.t0 <- function(params,x,y,var,fc,fe) {
    t0 <- params[1]
    output <- sum(((y-fc-fe * sin(2* pi *(x- t0)/12))/var)^2)
    return(output)
}





for (i in 1:200){
    for (j in 1:200){

        xmin <- optimize(fun.to.minimize.t0 , c(0, 1), fc = fc[i] , fe = fe[j] , x=months, y=frac, var=error)

        chisq2.matrix <- optim(c(fc[i],fe[j],xmin$objective), fun.to.minimize, x=months, y=frac, var= error)
        chisq.table[i, j] <- chisq2.matrix$value

    }
}


contour(x =fc,y = fe,
        z= chisq.table)
```

With this I got this plot.
[image]

I was hoping to get points in all regions and also how can I add Confidence Interval in this plot?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our tour, which has information for new users.  Since this looks like homework (apologies if it's not), please add the [self-study] tag and read its wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing. If this is self-study rather than homework, let us know, and... it's still a good idea to show us what you've tried.

Comment: @jbowman made changes and yes i tried myself but not getting what i desired